# I have a model method duedate and i want to save it's return value as a field to database

Tags: django-models

```
class License(models.Model):
    agency = models.ForeignKey(Agency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_person = models.ManyToManyField(ContactPerson())
    description = models.CharField("License Description", max_length=250)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    renewal_frequency = models.CharField("Enter number of moths", max_length=20)
    sop = models.FileField(upload_to="sop")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class Timeline(models.Model):
    license = models.ForeignKey(License, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_renewed = models.DateField()
    notification_period = models.CharField("Due date notificatio. (number in 
     months)", 
    max_length=2)
    lpo = models.FileField(upload_to="lpo")
    comment = models.TextField("Comment", max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    report = models.FileField(upload_to="reports", null=True,blank=True)
    renewed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def duedate(self):
    frequency = int(self.license.renewal_frequency)
    duedate = self.last_renewed + relativedelta(months=frequency)
    return duedate
```

*if i want to save the return value of duedate to my database. how would i do that.
due date is a model method that return the due date after evaluating the renewal date and the renewal frequency.*